# Open 'Smart Lock For Passwords' setting screen by code

Tags: android, google-smartlockpasswords

Is there a way to open the 'Smart Lock For Passwords' screen by code (ex. for opening GPS location by code we create a new intent with the following line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
```

Thanks,

Comment: I work on the Smart Lock team: we've discussed this, but weren't sure what the use case would be. How would you trigger this / what would the context of the UX flow for this be?

Comment: Let's look on the following User Story: When the user want to save password , the 'save password google dialog with Smart Lock' is shown with two options: 'Save Password' and 'Never'. The user than press on the never option (by mistake or not). The user is log in state but without saving his credentials. Now , the user want to change his user name. In the second user name he want to save his password . But now he can't. The only option for him his to go to the setting screen and remove the app from the 'Never save' this app and we want to help him with it.

Comment: I see, OK, thanks. I think this is reasonable to put on the feature request list.

Comment: @StevenSoneff this would be great! Many other parts of the settings menu are accessible by intents and the Smart Lock prompt to store password links to this menu, so I am surprised this feature is not already available.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to programmatically trigger the settings activity via a public API, but we've put it on the feature request list, and I'll update this answer when it becomes available.

Comment: You mean we cannot open smartlock GUI from intent. Please look at my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011144/how-to-open-smartlock-intent-in-android

Comment: Is it implemented in 2021?